# Сравнение строк в sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Суть такова. Есть две таблицы. Таблица стандарта, включающая в себя название профессии по стандарту и ее код. Вторая таблица профессий, введенная отделом кадров на предприятии. Введенные кадрами данные иногда отличаются от стандарта(не инженер, а инженер-электроник, к примеру). Нужно добавить к профессиям из второй таблицы коды из первой, включая те, которые названы не по стандарту. Пытаюсь делать с применением оператора LIKE, но не могу до конца реализовать, поскольку для LIKE нужно задавать шаблон, а мне надо как то сравнивать с стандартом без задания шаблона вручную, поскольку записей 5+к.

Comment: Вариант 1. Добавьте поле профессия_id, которое будет соответствовать полю id в первой таблице.Придется вручную один раз пройтись и проставить значение всем вариантами написания одной профессии. Вариант 2. Сделать третью таблицу с вариантами написания одной и той же профессии, и использовать её для связки. LIKE не всегда может однозначно работать

Comment: Не берите на себя ответственность установления соответствия. Будете крайним. А ошибки обязательно будут. Задача решается административно - подключите кадрам стандарт, и пусть соответствуют. А где не соответствуют - пусть исправляют. Им. в конце концов, за это платят.

Comment: стандартом надо полагать вы классификатор ОКПДТР называете?